# Use XOR in a calculated column in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, calculated-column-formula

Is it possible to use the XOR operator in a calculated SharePoint column in a list? If yes, what is the syntax for it and can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this function in SharePoint.

In Excel we can do this using

```
=XOR(condition1,condition2)
```

If it fails then you need to stick with `if`

```
=IF(condition,TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(condition1,TRUE,IF(condition2,TRUE,FALSE)
... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does only do IF, AND, OR and NOT for Logical functions so you have to built a XOR with those.